# expected primary-expression before 'int'

Tags: c++

I make code about linked list. But it has an error `expected primary-expression before 'int'`

I write the code using class template :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class ChainNode{
    friend class Chain;
    public:
        ChainNode(T paraData=0, ChainNode<T> *paraLink=0):
            data(paraData),link(paraLink){
        }
    private:
        T data;
        ChainNode<T> *link;
};

template <class T>
class Chain{
    public:
        Chain(){
            first=0;
            last=0;
        }
        void insertBack(T& e){
            if(first){
                last=last->link= new ChainNode<T>(e, 0);
            }else{
                first=last=new ChainNode<T>(e, 0);
            }
        }
    private:
        ChainNode<T> *first;
        ChainNode<T> *last;
};

int main()
{
    Chain<int> a;
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
        a.insertBack<int>(i); // <<at here expected primary-expression before 'int' occurs 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, what is that supposed to mean: `a.insertBack<int>(i)`? What did you try to express by this syntax? Why did you put that `<int>` after `insertBack`?

Comment: That's my fault... erase <int>

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to give the template argument.

```
a.insertBack(i);
```